# Explanation on WordPress' rewrite rules

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I found these rewrite rules in the .htaccess of my WordPress site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I know that this basically refers everything to index.php. But how does it work? What rule does what?

Comment: I had the same question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/35303598/2983568), and found detailed explanation here: http://glennmessersmith.com/pages/wphtaccess.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found some reference here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

`RewriteEngine On` enables the rewrite module.

`RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` makes sure that if `index.php` is called, no other rules are executed. The `-` is to make sure no rewrite will occur, and the `[L]` flag indicates that no other rules should be executed.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` adds a condition to the following rewrite rule. This condition says that the requested filename is *not* (`!`) an existing file.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is the same, but for an existing directory.

`RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` says that *everything* (`.`) should be rewritten to `/index.php`, and that this is the last rule to execute (`[L]`).